# Magento 2 How do I sort mini cart items?

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I am trying to sort the items based on the product ordered qty.

**Is there any logical method to the way cart items are sorted by ordered qty?**

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am trying to sort items in minicart based on their price.

Comment: @k185 have you found any clue from my answer below

Comment: @AmritPalSingh I tried to extend the Cart.php but I keep getting 'php fatal error'
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1da881faae7f0cea553f5fb05a67d95663b042b

Answer (score 5):

You can use `getItems()` plugin to Sort Quote Items:

Create This Plugin:

**MODULE\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart">
        <plugin name="item_filter" type="[Your]\[Module]\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart" />
</type>
```

**MODULE\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart**:

```
public function afterGetItems(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart $subject){
     $items = [];
     $totalItems = [];
     $itemAdded = [];

     foreach ($subject->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $totalItems[] = $item->getId();

        if(/*Your Condition*/){
            /*you can sort item by qty wise*/
            /*you can get qty using $item->getQty();*/
           $itemAdded[] = $item;
           $items[] = $item;
        }

     }
     $result = array_diff($totalItems, $itemAdded);

     foreach ($result as $quoteid) {
        if($quoteid){
            $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($quoteid);
            $items[] = $item;
        }
     }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how I should implement the Cart.php, I added the blog after 'public function getItems()' but after compile it shows 
MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart, because the name is already in use in /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/MYSITE/MYMODULE/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Cart.php on line 272

Comment: @k185 you can give any other name also for cart.php. I have just created a after plugin for getItems() method.

Comment: Or you might have given wrong namespace to that class .`Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart`, it should be `Your\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart`

Comment: @k185 does this works for you?

Comment: that fixed the issue

Comment: @Navin Bhudiya accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: You only posted half of the code

Answer (score 1):

First create a plugin,

In di.xml use :

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
     <plugin name="SortByQty" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cart"/>
</type>
```

Then in Cart.php add a function afterGetSectionData,

Now the logic will be done for sorting but i can tell the starting:

```
public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result){


        $items = $result['items'];

        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            $_productId = $value['product_id'];
            $_productPrice = $value['product_price_value'];
            $_productQty = $value['qty'];
            $_productTotal = $_productPrice * $_productQty;
        }

         $data = [
            'items' => $items
         ];

        return $result = array_merge($data, $result);
}
```